# Joomla 3.2 Guest user group

Tags: joomla, authentication, hide

I'm working on a website based on Joomla 3.2.
I created menu module with a menu item called login and I want that this menu item only is shown to guest users. The item is suppose to disappear as soon the user is logged in.

To achieve that I gave that menu item, the access level guest. In the past I have done something like that on Joomla 2.5 already and it worked but now it doesn't work at all.

The only hint I could get was to change the default user groupe for guest users from public to guest, but still no success.

I hope someone can help me to  figure out this problem.

Comment: Okay I figured it out,

Just after my post I stumbled other this:)

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_hide_something_from_logged_in_users%3F

This is for joomla 2.5 but works on 3.2 as well.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: please write an answer and mark it as correct to show this has been solved

Answer (score 3):

In Joomla 3 you have Public and Guest user groups. Public is what you want for all pages and items that anyone can see.
For items that just non logged in users see you need to assign them to Guest. Which a user will not then see.

This how to for 3.1 is quite good

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/extension/hide-module-after-login

Answer (score 0):

When you perform all steps, and it's still not working. Then logout, clear browser cache/session data etc and then try again, this worked for me